# CSS First Letter Highlighting

Tags: html, css, pseudo-element

I understand that with CSS formatting the first letter of each paragraph is possible via:

```
p:first-letter
{
font-size:20px;
}
```

However upon using this code it is impossible to highlight/select these "First Letters" from the web browser, is there a way to amend this?

Edit - It is possible to select the text, however it isn't shown visually, how can I change this?

Comment: Who told you they don't get selected? http://jsfiddle.net/kHe4P/

Comment: The do not get selected in Webkit browsers

Comment: @Mr.Alien in your fiddle, it isn't selectable

Comment: It isn't visually highlighted, but it actually is. If you copy your `ello` selection it will give you `Hello`

Comment: Is there a way to Visually Highlight it still? 
I'm using the p::selection method to change the selection colour but no luck

Comment: @Kehza I'm not sure. You could always wrap the first letter in a `span` if possible and then target `p > span { font-size:20px; }` but this is a workaround.

Comment: It is a bug in WebKit. It is selectable in all other browsers.

Comment: Yeah I was thinking of doing that @danrhul, it however does mean more code and time. 
Really? I'll test it out now dstorey thanks

Comment: The language is just called CSS, by the way, not CSS3.

Comment: @BoltClock, Nice one :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a bug in Chrome/ium/WebKit: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=17528

Answer (score 1):

Right, it is not visually selected but in the background it is. If I select and copy and then paste it, I get "Hello" so this just might be a problem with the different font-sizes. font-variant:small-caps works perfectly (but uses uppercase).

You might want to try Lettering.js or alternatives
http://letteringjs.com/
https://github.com/davatron5000/Lettering.js