# Selection does not match cursor position caused by white-space and css

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I noticed that a selection on my web page is not matching the cursor position. I dug deep and found following causes:

1. White-space between start tag `<p>` and first sentence,
2. Css: `p:first-letter { font-size: 1.2em; }`,
3. Chrome browser (? maybe not the only one).

Here is minimal example:

HTML:

```
<p>
    Try to select me. See? Broken (in Chrome at least).
</p>
<p>This one is just fine because there is no whitepsace</p>
```

CSS:

```
p:first-letter {
    font-size: 1.5em;
}
```

JsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/r1jyzLkt/1/

I find this really weird behavior. Can anyone please explain this to me and how to possibly fix it while keeping both white-space and CSS? Thanks!

Update: I do not really care about the first letter selection, here is the animation what I am observing, do you see the wrong offset?

[image: Wrong selection offset]

Comment: Wow.  The second one in your fiddle can't be selected from the start of the line either, for me (only from 'is one is...' onwards.

Comment: I am actually observing this for a longer time now but lately it started to really annoy me - the selection is like 2 cm off (Chrome 37.0.2062.103 m, Win7)

Comment: @NightElfik Does this change anything for you? http://jsfiddle.net/mL11qtpn/

Comment: @NightElfik In IE 10 both selections in your fiddle works fine for me.  But in Chrome neither line can be selected from the beginning.  Also for Josh Crozier's fiddle - same behaviour.

Comment: I'm also getting the same behavior as Stefan is getting.

Comment: It's a good observation, but before you ask a question on SO it would be really nice if you tried to isolate the problem yourself. In this instance, it seems to me as though you could have tried other browsers to confirm whether it's a Chrome bug or not for example.

Comment: @Ian Clark: I would say, not everyone necessarily wants to install multiple browsers on their computer.

Comment: It's a bug as of this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16597114/1712600

Comment: @JoshCrozier It does not change anything, selection is still 2 cm off. And I did not tired it in other browsers since I don't have them currently installed. I spent like an hour recognizing the root causes.

Comment: Here's a discussion on SO - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7631722/css-first-letter-not-working. I played around a bit and by changing to inline-block it works ok.

Comment: possible duplicate of [CSS First Letter Highlighting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16592632/css-first-letter-highlighting)

Answer (score 0):

Can you use html comment?

```
<p><!--
    -->Try to select me. See? Broken (in Chrome at least).
</p>
```

Comment: Thanks, that workaround actually works but it is quite inconvenient to write "random" comments to comment-out white-spaces.