# CSS ::first-letter styles ignores custom selection styles

Tags: html, css

I have an element that i want to style, and i want to style on the `first-letter`, but when i do that and select the text the text selection color changes, how can i fix that?

```css
div::first-letter {
color: red;
text-transform: uppercase;
}

::-moz-selection {
  background-color: rgb(21 174 159 / 0.6) !important;
}

::selection {
  background-color: rgb(21 174 159 / 0.6) !important;
}
```

```html
<div>some text</div>
```

Edit: Its not `text-transform: uppercase` thats causing the problem, its `::first-letter` itself

Comment: @Ram not "ruins", it just ignores the selection styles

Comment: This was highlighted as a bug in Chrome (it works fine in FF for example on my Windows10) just over 9 years ago at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72577729/css-text-transform-uppercase-ignores-custom-selection-styles Looks like it's still a bug (and also a bug therefore in Edge).

Comment: @AHaworth your link is to this post, not the one you referenced from 9 years ago

Comment: @AHaworth Weird, Guess ill have to capitalize the first character in javascript instead

Comment: Thanks for spotting @GonePhishing The link to that item is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16592632/css-first-letter-highlighting